# How to use a script to add a line to a specific line number in another script file, both stored as variables?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a shell script that is trying to add a line to a specific line number in another script file.

Currently, I have the target line number  and the string itself saved as variables as:

```
target=238
string="fooBar"
```

i tried: `sed -i "'$target'i '$string'" my_file`
and

`sed -i "${target}i, ${string}" my_file`

The end goal should go from:

```
236:AAAAA
237:BBBBB
238:CCCC
239:DDDD
```

To:

```
236:AAAAA
237:BBBBB
238:fooBar
239:CCCC
240:DDDD
```

But I am running into "Illegal option -- i" when using that command.
Is there a way around using sed, or a different method?

I have also tried: `perl -i -pe 'if($. == "$target") {s//"$string"\n/}' in_file`
but that has not worked either.

Using hard coded values, the command above worked, just not with variables. Ex: `perl -i -pe 'if($. == 8) {s//Hello\n/}' in_file`
inserts "Hello" at the 8th line and bumps everything down.

Comment: Just `"${target}i${string}"` , you are putting too many quotes and `,` there.

Comment: Are the line numbers actually included in the file? Or have you prepended them to the lines just for explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` option is not portable. If your `sed` version tells you that it doesn't support it, you'll have to store the output in a temporary file and then move it back on top of the input file.

As to the actual script, the `i` command in `sed` behaves slightly differently on different platforms. The script should certainly not have any single quotes around the `sed` commands; perhaps try

```
sed "${target}i\\
$string" my_file >temp
mv temp my_file
```

The backslash and newline is required on some platforms but not on others. If this syntax doesn't work on yours, try variations without them, etc. (The double-quoted string means the backslash needs to be doubled, as the shell will remove one layer of backslashes when removing the quotes. In this particular case, you could get away with a single backslash, but it's clearer IMHO to double all literal backslashes.)

If you need a portable solution, perhaps it's easier to switch to e.g. Awk.

```
awk -v n="$target" -v s="$string" '
NR==n { print s } 1' my_file >temp
mv temp my_file
```

GNU Awk has an `-i inplace` option which works similarly to `sed -i` but again, if your `sed` doesn't support `-i`, you are likely on a platform where you don't have GNU Awk, either.

Finally, you might also consider Perl, which does have an `-i` option if you have Perl at all. The code is not exactly simpler than the Awk script, but you can avoid the separate `mv`.

```
perl -pi -le 'BEGIN { $n = shift @ARGV;
    $s = shift @ARGV
} { print $s if $. == $n }
' "$target" "$string" my_file
```

Demo (without `-i`): https://ideone.com/st9h6l

Comment: how do i write the line so it does not print out the old file and new file? I just want it to write to the file. I tried removing the p flag in the perl line but that did not work.

Comment: It's not clear which version you are asking about. The `mv` command will replace the input file with the new output file.